# MemoryCache - Login Security

Tags: c#, security, authentication

I have a WCF service which should authenticate user against any bruteforce attack.
Below is the code to avoid any bruteforce attack. I have used `MemoryCache` to keep track of invalid attempts by a user.

Could you please review the code and let me know if there are any issues?

Following defined in config file:

```
<InvalidLoginAttemptsThreshold value = "5"/>
<InvalidLoginLockoutInMinutes value = "20"/>
```

Code to add invalid login to cache and lock the account if invalid logins reaches threshold set in config.

```
private readonly CacheItemPolicy cacheInvalidLoginPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();
private readonly ObjectCache cacheInvalidLogins = MemoryCache.Default; //Cache to hold Invalid Login Attempts: {UserId, obj UserLogin}

public class UserLogin
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public List<DateTime> InvalidLoginTimestamp { get; set; }
    public bool IsLocked { get; set; }
}
private bool AuthenticateUser(string userName, string password)
{
    bool validCredentials = false;
    string userNameUpperCase = userName.ToUpper(); //MemoryCache treats 'a' and 'A' as different names
    if (cacheInvalidLogins.Contains(userNameUpperCase) && ((UserLogin)cacheInvalidLogins[userNameUpperCase]).IsLocked)
    {
        log.ErrorFormat("UserId: {0} tried to access locked account at {1}", userName, DateTime.Now);
        throw new FaultException("Your account is locked out. Please try after some time.", new FaultCode("AccountLocked")); 
    }

    try
    {
        validCredentials = securityService.Authenticate(userName, password);

        if (!validCredentials)
        {
            AddInvalidLoginToCache(userNameUpperCase);
        }
        else if (validCredentials && cacheInvalidLogins.Contains(userNameUpperCase))
        {
            //For valid credentials - remove from cache
            cacheInvalidLogins.Remove(userNameUpperCase);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        log.Error(exception);
    }

    return validCredentials;
}

private void AddInvalidLoginToCache(string userName)
{
    if (cacheInvalidLogins.Contains(userName))
    {
        string clientId = userName.Split('\\')[0];
        //Increment InvalidLoginCount for this user
        UserLogin invalidLogin = (UserLogin)cacheInvalidLogins[userName];
        invalidLogin.InvalidLoginTimestamp.Add(DateTime.Now);
        cacheInvalidLogins[userName] = invalidLogin; //todo: update cache policy here

        //Lock user account if InvalidLoginCount reach threshold set in config
        if (invalidLogin.InvalidLoginTimestamp.Count == invalidLoginThresholdFromConfig))
        {
            invalidLogin.IsLocked = true;
            cacheInvalidLogins.Set(userName.ToUpper(), invalidLogin, LockOutCachePolicyFromConfig());
            log.ErrorFormat("Invalid Login attempted by UserId: {0} at these timestamps: {1}", userName, String.Join(",", invalidLogin.InvalidLoginTimestamp));
            log.ErrorFormat("Account is locked out for UserId: {0}", userName);
            throw new FaultException("Your account is locked out. Please try after some time.", new FaultCode("AccountLocked")); 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //todo: check if extra config setting is required for this cache policy
        cacheInvalidLoginPolicy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(5);
        cacheInvalidLogins.Add(userName.ToUpper(),
                               new UserLogin {UserName = userName, InvalidLoginTimestamp = new List<DateTime> {DateTime.Now}},
                               cacheInvalidLoginPolicy);
    }
}
```

Comment: What type/class is `securityService`?

Answer (score 4):

1. If I'm right it's not thread-safe. I suppose two browsers with the same username could login at the same time which means that the `AuthenticateUser` method runs parallel on two threads.

   Suppose the following:

   - the user already has an invalid login attempt,
   - two new threads enter `AddInvalidLoginToCache` the same time,
   - `invalidLoginThresholdFromConfig = 2`.

   A possible execution order is the following:

   ```
   // InvalidLoginTimestamp.Count = 1, we already have an invalid login attempt
   thread1: enters AddInvalidLoginToCache
   thread2: enters AddInvalidLoginToCache
   thread1: runs invalidLogin.InvalidLoginTimestamp.Add(DateTime.Now); // InvalidLoginTimestamp.Count = 2
   thread2: runs invalidLogin.InvalidLoginTimestamp.Add(DateTime.Now); // InvalidLoginTimestamp.Count = 3
   thread1: runs if (invalidLogin.InvalidLoginTimestamp.Count == 2)) // false 
   thread2: runs if (invalidLogin.InvalidLoginTimestamp.Count == 2)) // false
   ```

   The result is that a lucky attacker will never be locked out.

   The second problem is visibility. Since `InvalidLoginTimestamp` and `invalidLogin` are shared between threads you need some synchronization to ensure other threads will see modifications (not just stale data or invalid state).

   - [C# multi-threading: Acquire read lock necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1668719/843804)
   - [How to synchronize the access to a List used in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/186550/843804)
2. > ```
   > private readonly ObjectCache cacheInvalidLogins = MemoryCache.Default; //Cache to hold Invalid Login Attempts: {UserId, obj UserLogin}
   > ```

   I'd put the comment before the line to avoid horizontal scrolling:

   ```
   //Cache to hold Invalid Login Attempts: {UserId, obj UserLogin}
   private readonly ObjectCache cacheInvalidLogins = MemoryCache.Default;
   ```

   Furthermore, I'd rename it to `invalidLoginAttemptsCache`. The `cacheInvalidLogins` name looks like a method name since it starts with a verb (`cache...`).
3. > ```
   > bool validCredentials = false;
   > ... // other statements
   > try
   > {
   >     validCredentials = securityService.Authenticate(userName, password);
   > ```

   The boolean could be declared right before the first use with a smaller scope:

   ```
   ...  // other statements
   bool validCredentials = false;
   try
   {
       validCredentials = securityService.Authenticate(userName, password);
   ```

   [Should I declare variables as close as possible to the scope where they will be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6133586/843804)
4. > ```
   > private void AddInvalidLoginToCache(string userName)
   > {
   >     ...
   >     cacheInvalidLogins.Set(userName.ToUpper(), invalidLogin, LockOutCachePolicyFromConfig());
   > ```

   The code calls this method with the uppercased username. I'd rename the parameter to `upperCasedUserName` and remove the `.ToUpper()` call.
5. This variable is never user, I guess you could remove it:

   > ```
   > string clientId = userName.Split('\\')[0];
   > ```
6. [*Username* seems to be one word](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/43436/13023), I'd not capitalize the `n`.